# Creating conditional sql query

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I am having a problem getting a query to work (and also am questioning the security of the query).

```
  if(isset($_POST)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE";

     if($_POST['FirstName_S'] !== ''){
        $sql .= " FirstName LIKE '%" . $_POST['FirstName_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['LastName_S'] !== ''){
        $sql .= " OR LastName LIKE '%" . $_POST['LastName_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['Firm_S'] !== ''){
        $sql .= " OR Firm LIKE '%" . $_POST['Firm_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['Country_S'] !== ''){
        $sql .= " OR Country LIKE '%" . $_POST['Country_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['City_S'] !== ''){
        $sql .= " OR City LIKE '%" . $_POST['City_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['State_S'] !== '' AND $_POST['State_S'] !== 'other'){
        $sql .= " OR State LIKE '%" . $_POST['State_S'] . "%'";
     }
  }
```

Obviously, if FirstName_S is undefined, the query breaks saying "WHERE OR". It seems like it would have a logical fix, but I've been staring at it for a little too long.

Also, sql injection was brought up as a concern, and as a side-question, would sanitizing the input be enough? Or is this altogether bad practice?

Comment: Is `FirstName_S` required to be sent in the `POST`?

Comment: no, it's not. It's just a search function where users can look up members in a database. You can just enter any one of these alone, or with others.

Comment: To protect from SQL Injections, prepared statements are best: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Comment: Move the `OR` from the beginning to the end of the line

Comment: Just end the query with `WHERE 1=1`. Then you can append any number of  `OR something` without being concerned about omitting the `OR` from the first one. (There are some query builder tools that use this technique.) If you are using mysql interface, yes, sanitize the post variables. If you are using mysqli or PDO (and you should be) use parameterized queries. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  if(isset($_POST)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE";

     if($_POST['FirstName_S'] !== ''){
        $sql .= "OR FirstName LIKE '%" . $_POST['FirstName_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['LastName_S'] !== ''){
        $sql .= " OR LastName LIKE '%" . $_POST['LastName_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['Firm_S'] !== ''){
        $sql .= " OR Firm LIKE '%" . $_POST['Firm_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['Country_S'] !== ''){
        $sql .= " OR Country LIKE '%" . $_POST['Country_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['City_S'] !== ''){
        $sql .= " OR City LIKE '%" . $_POST['City_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['State_S'] !== '' AND $_POST['State_S'] !== 'other'){
        $sql .= " OR State LIKE '%" . $_POST['State_S'] . "%'";
     }

    $sql=str_replace("WHERE OR","WHERE",$sql);   // quick dirty fix

  }
```

Ofcourse you'd need to sanitize the input, but since you didn't mention which MySQL API you use, I did not add any sanitization functions yet. You can look at http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: If first-name is not defined - the query will fail

Comment: Nope it will not, can you tell me how?

Comment: Now that you added your "quick dirty fix" it won't fail

Comment: I didn't add it Now, that was my original answer that quick dirty fix, review the edit history.

Comment: Yep that OR still is only cosmetic, that query will still work with or without it

Answer (score 2):

do it other way as follow

```
if(isset($_POST)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE";

     if($_POST['FirstName_S'] !== ''){
        $sql_arr[]=" FirstName LIKE '%" . $_POST['FirstName_S'] . "%'";

     }
     if($_POST['LastName_S'] !== ''){
        $sql_arr[]= " LastName LIKE '%" . $_POST['LastName_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['Firm_S'] !== ''){
        $sql_arr[]= " Firm LIKE '%" . $_POST['Firm_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['Country_S'] !== ''){
        $sql_arr[]= " Country LIKE '%" . $_POST['Country_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['City_S'] !== ''){
        $sql_arr[]= " City LIKE '%" . $_POST['City_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if($_POST['State_S'] !== '' AND $_POST['State_S'] !== 'other'){
        $sql_arr[]= " State LIKE '%" . $_POST['State_S'] . "%'";
     }
     if(!empty($sql_arr)){
       $sql.=implode(' OR ',$sql_arr);
}

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The quick fix is to add `1=1` to your query, so your query ends with `WHERE 1=1`. That allows you to be free to append any number of `OR something` to your query, without being concerned with omitting the `OR` on the first one.

(That 1=1 predicate doesn't cause any problem; that will be evaluated at parse time, and doesn't appear in the execution plan.)

As to SQL Injection, yes, this code is susceptible. If you are using mysql interface, then sanitize the post variables with `mysql_real_escape_string` function. If you are using mysqli or PDO (and you should be), then use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE FirstName LIKE ? OR LastName LIKE ? OR FIRM LIKE ? OR Country LIKE ? OR CITY LIKE ? OR STATE LIKE ?');


if($_POST['FirstName_S'] !== ''){
  $stmt->bind_param('FirstName', '%'.$_POST['FirstName_S'].'%');
} else {
  $stmt->bind_param('FirstName', '%');
}

… // do this for all your parameters

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members";

 if($_POST['FirstName_S'] !== ''){
    $sql .= " WHERE FirstName LIKE '%" . $_POST['FirstName_S'] . "%'";
 }
 else {
   $sql .= " WHERE FirstName LIKE '%'";
 }
 if($_POST['LastName_S'] !== ''){
    $sql .= " OR LastName LIKE '%" . $_POST['LastName_S'] . "%'";
 }
 if($_POST['Firm_S'] !== ''){
    $sql .= " OR Firm LIKE '%" . $_POST['Firm_S'] . "%'";
 }
 if($_POST['Country_S'] !== ''){
    $sql .= " OR Country LIKE '%" . $_POST['Country_S'] . "%'";
 }
 if($_POST['City_S'] !== ''){
    $sql .= " OR City LIKE '%" . $_POST['City_S'] . "%'";
 }
 if($_POST['State_S'] !== '' AND $_POST['State_S'] !== 'other'){
    $sql .= " OR State LIKE '%" . $_POST['State_S'] . "%'";
 }
```

}

and for the SQL injections, you can check General_Twyckenham comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could compose the WHERE command based on what parameters is entered...

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $sql_where = '';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members ";

    if($_POST['FirstName_S'] !== ''){
        $sql_where .= (($sql_where != '')?('OR '):(''))." FirstName LIKE '%" . $_POST['FirstName_S'] . "%' ";
    }
    if($_POST['LastName_S'] !== ''){
        $sql_where .= (($sql_where != '')?('OR '):(''))." LastName LIKE '%" . $_POST['LastName_S'] . "%' ";
    }
    if($_POST['Firm_S'] !== ''){
        $sql_where .= (($sql_where != '')?('OR '):(''))." Firm LIKE '%" . $_POST['Firm_S'] . "%' ";
    }
    if($_POST['Country_S'] !== ''){
        $sql_where .= (($sql_where != '')?('OR '):(''))." Country LIKE '%" . $_POST['Country_S'] . "%' ";
    }
    if($_POST['City_S'] !== ''){
        $sql_where .= (($sql_where != '')?('OR '):(''))." City LIKE '%" . $_POST['City_S'] . "%' ";
    }
    if($_POST['State_S'] !== '' AND $_POST['State_S'] !== 'other'){
        $sql_where .= (($sql_where != '')?('OR '):(''))." State LIKE '%" . $_POST['State_S'] . "%' ";
    }
    $sql .= (($sql_where != '')?('WHERE '.sql_where):(''));
}
```